# can a class be extended with Activity and View, at a time?

Tags: android, view, canvas, drawing

i am new to android, and developing a snake/ladder game . i am using a statically defined image(10*10 board with snake n ladders drawn over it). i have defind this image in an xml(start.xml) file n setting this xml file in setContentView()(in start.java) . i also used button n edit boxes in the xml file. 
the button is dice. i want to move the player position(in the form of drawing circle,each time, over the board image). .but drawing requires the class to be extended by view whereas, my class is extending activity..
how can i solve this issue???? i need a precise answer.
Regards,
Touqeer Fatima Malik

Answer (score 0):

you can extend a view like this

```
MyView extends ImageView { ...
```

and use it in the xml as

```
<com.my.app.MyView ...
```

Comment: cud u plz explain that, wat is "com.my.app" is??? is it a package name,followed by the class name?????

Comment: @A.Q.Ghouri: yes it is package name followed by class name